# Matlab c embedded coder code

Tags: c, matlab, syntax, matlab-coder

```
  b_k = 1;
  while (b_k <= iv0[1]) {
    h = vplus_data[0];
    u1 = vmax->data[(int)((1.0 + (double)k) + 1.0) - 1];
    if ((h <= u1) || rtIsNaN(u1)) {
      minval_data_idx_0 = h;
    } else {
      minval_data_idx_0 = u1;
    }

    b_k = 2;
  }

  b_k = 1;
  while (b_k <= iv0[1]) {
    h = vmin->data[(int)((1.0 + (double)k) + 1.0) - 1];
    if ((h >= minval_data_idx_0) || rtIsNaN(minval_data_idx_0)) {
    } else {
      h = minval_data_idx_0;
    }

    vplus_data[0] = h;
    b_k = 2;
  }
```

this code is compared to min function to get the minimum value for h or u1,
can anyone tell me why matlab generate such syntax? why is the while loop, although I dont see any changes inside the while block!

**matlab code**

```
v(k+1) = max(vmin(k+1), min(vplus, vmax(k+1)));
```

notice there are two loops for max min function

Comment: It's probably this way as a side effect of how you wrote your Matlab code. Can you post the Matlab code?

Comment: `b_k` starts as `1` (in the line `b_k = 1;`, and becomes `2` (in the line `b_k = 2;`); clearly that is a change inside the block. Not sure why it is there, but it is there.

Comment: I edited the post, what more, is that the second loop repeat without any code change!!

Comment: I agree it is bizarre. More important question - does it work?

Comment: yes, it work, and what surpprizes me, overall the big function is 50% faster than the c++ code I am comparing with

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain why the generated code ends up like that, but it must have something to do with how you wrote your Matlab code. It looks strange, but if it works then it probably doesn't matter.

If you're curious about the generator, start from something very simple and watch how the generated code changes as your code gets more complex. Try variations like these:

```
z = min(x, y);

z = max(w, min(x, y));

for i = 1:length(v)
    z(i) = max(w, min(v(i), y));
end
```

Keep on modifying the test code a bit at a time to make it like the code that prompted this question and maybe you'll discover exactly what triggers the result you're seeing.